# installing GNU GUILE

Tags: installation, environment-variables

I want to install guile at a custom location so downloaded the source code and am trying to configure it from with the following command:

`./configure --prefix=/home/aman/voxsup-analytics/compiler_build/ins --with-libltdl-prefix=/home/aman/voxsup-analytics/compiler/libtool-2.4/`

I have installed libtool at location `/home/aman/voxsup-analytics/compiler/libtool-2.4/` and have added the `/home/aman/voxsup-analytics/compiler/libtool-2.4/bin` to path (bin directory of libtool). I always get the following error

```
checking for libltdl... no
configure: error: GNU libltdl (Libtool) not found, see README.`
```

While I am able to run libtool from my shell I cannot understand why this is happening.

The source of guile can be downloaded from [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/guile/) and I am using fedora redhat 16

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered this problem today.
I've finally solved this problem after trying for a long time.

You need to add LDFLAGS=-L/home/aman/voxsup-analytics/compiler/libtool-2.4/lib to the congfigure command.

Hope this could help you and also help others.